# wxPython hypertreelist set item to checked

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I'm trying to build a simple interface with hypertreelist. Basically, what I want to do, is set the item to a checked state. There is the function `.IsChecked()` to retrieve the checkbox status on an item, but no `SetCheck()` or `SetValue()`. Any idea on how to do this?

I suppose I need to access the checkbox object inside the TreeListItem, but I have no clue on how to do that. The [documentation](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.hypertreelist.TreeListItem.html) on that isn't really helpful.

Here's part of my code:

```
self.view.tree_list.AddColumn('Available columns')
root = self.view.tree_list.AddRoot('All columns', ct_type=1)
branches = {}
for item in self.possibleColumns:
    branches[item] = self.columnsView.tree_list.AppendItem(root, item, ct_type=1)
    if item in self.wantedColumns:
         # set to checked
```

where `wantedColumns` and `possibleColumns` are array of strings. (the frame will help decide which columns to show in another tab)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HyperTreeList inherits from GenericTreeItem:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.customtreectrl.GenericTreeItem.html#lib.agw.customtreectrl.GenericTreeItem

It would appear that you can use its Check() method to toggle whether a tree item is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just been struggling with this also, here my solution:

```
import wx.lib.agw.hypertreelist as HTL 

self.tree_list =self.createTree()
self.tree_list.AddColumn("File")
self.tree_list.AddColumn("Size")
#self.tree_list.AssignImageList(some image_list)
self.root =self.tree_list.AddRoot("abc", ct_type=1)
for my_text in [ 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl' ]:
    node =self.tree_list.AppendItem( self.root, testware_path, ct_type =1)
    self.tree_list.SetItemText( node, text=my_text, column=1)
    self.tree_list.SetItemText( node, text=my_text, column=2)
    if my_text.startswith('d'):
        node.Check()
```